# How to filter string "1M,3F,2M" to "1,3,2" through jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have String 2M,1F,5M,6F selected seats with gender. how to filter this string to only numbers with comma?

something like this,

```
stringVal.replace(/, /g, ",").replace(/,/g, ", ");
```

this one returns with space after comma but i want only numbers with comma.

Comment: Use `.replace(/[^\d,]+/g, '')`

Answer (score 4):

Why not replace all alphabetical characters with the empty string?

```js
const stringVal = '1M,3F,2M';
console.log(
  stringVal.replace(/[a-z]/gi, '')
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split()` on comma and then `parseInt()` each value of array to get the number and then `join()` it using comma.

```js
var stringVal = '1M,3F,2M';
stringVal = stringVal.split(',').map(x=> parseInt(x)).join(',');
console.log(stringVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for getting numbers,

```js
console.log('2M,1F,5M,6F'.replace(/[^\d,]+/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have String 2M,1F,5M,6F selected seats with gender

It seems the string contains `M` and `F` so you can replace those with empty string.

```js
var stringVal = '2M,1F,5M,6F'

stringVal = stringVal.replace(/[MF]/g, "")
console.log(stringVal);
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, not with `/[MF]/g`

Comment: Your code is very limited and doesn't work if string contain another letter

Comment: @Mohammad, I think the pattern does not say it will contain other characters.

Comment: Since it's related to gender I think M and F would be the only letters that will contain in this String

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `split` directly on the input string to generate an output *array* of values:

```js
var input = "2M,1F,5M,6F";
input = input + ",";
var genders = input.split(/[A-Z],/);
genders.pop();
console.log(genders);
```

We add a trailing comma to the end of the input string, so that the split pattern will fire (and consume) the very last comma and gender code.  But this produces an extra empty entry in the output array, which we then pop off.

The possible advantage of this approach might be if you needed to have these values in an array anyway, and you wanted to achieve this in a single step.